# Powershell using Foreach-ObjectFast and Where-ObjectFast

Tags: windows, powershell, csv

I never really worked with Powershell, so I am quite stuck with this. My goal is to merge multiple CSV's into 1, more specifically 3 at the moment.

Using *Import-Csv* and *Foreach-Object* I managed to achieve this, however super-incredibly slow. I have discovered [this article](https://powershell.one/tricks/performance/pipeline) so I gave it a try. Incredible fast iteration.

Unfortunately I am too dumb with Powershell to understand why I cannot use *Where-ObjectFast* properly, it won't match anything.

My code example:

```
Measure-Command {   $CSV1 = Import-CSV -Path .\CSV1.csv }

Measure-Command {   $CSV2 = Import-CSV -Path .\CSV2.csv }

Measure-Command {

Import-Csv -Path .\CSV3.csv | Foreach-ObjectFast {
            $row = $_;
            $match = $CSV1 | Where-ObjectFast -FilterScript {       $_.name -eq $row.'name'     }
            $dbg1 = 'Matched: {0}' -f $match;   Write-Host $dbg1 -foreground Cyan;

   # continued... } }
```

What I need to do basically is to match "name" from CVS3 with "name" from CSV1, and other fields as needed, then do the same for CSV2 and output to a final file.

It seems that when using *Where-ObjectFast* $_ is empty (?).

Please advise what I am doing wrong here, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you're having is not with the overhead from `ForEach-Object` binding and processing the input - so replacing `ForEach-Object` with `ForEach-ObjectFast` is not going to have a significant impact.

If you want to pivot on the `name` column (or any other column), build index tables with a hashtable/dictionary:

```
$CSV1 = @{}
Import-Csv -Path .\CSV1.csv |ForEach-Object { $CSV1[$_.name] = $_ }

$CSV2 = @{}
Import-Csv -Path .\CSV2.csv |ForEach-Object { $CSV2[$_.id] = $_ }
```

Now you don't need to wait for `Where-Object` to search through each collection:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\CSV3.csv |ForEach-Object {
  $row = $_
  # This is going to be MUCH faster than ... |Where-Object { ... }
  $csv1match = $CSV1[$row.name]
  $csv2match = $CSV1[$row.id]

  # join $row,$csv1match,$csv2match here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I failed to mention that CSV3 is HUGE, which is why I used Import-Csv + ForEach-Object after doing some research. I also failed to mention that I need "all the data" from each row from CSV1, CSV2 so I can match them with "id"/"name" from CSV3 and then create my CSV4 as a final output.

Comment: @NorbertBoros you might be able to get a bit out of using the pipeline or switching to `ForEach-ObjectFast`, but the big killer is definitely going to be the lookups against the other data sets. The nice thing about this approach is you can build multiple indices up front if preferable (eg. `$CSV1ByName = @{}; $CSV1ById = @{}; Import-Csv ...|ForEach-Object {$CSV1ByName[$_.name] = $CSV1ById[$_.id] = $_}`) :)

Comment: Understood, I`m definitely doing some tests now. Just an FYI because once again I failed to mention something, is that CSV3 will match "name" from CSV1 and will match "id" from CSV2. Sorry for being dumb, first time using PS - LOL.

Comment: I think using foreach is doing the same issue I had before (loads the whole file into memory); it eats up all the RAM. My test so far failed :( The machine runs out of RAM and dies... the CSV3 is like 300 MB and I have even bigger ones.

Comment: @NorbertBoros Makes sense if it's huge, I've updated the answer to use `ForEach-Object` instead (it'll start processing the input as soon as it becomes available)

Comment: Thank you, thank you. This was driving me nuts. I have so many more questions... I don't even know if I should post them all. For example, I noticed some "name" from CSV3 is not present in CSV1; I would need to keep track of that somehow so when everything is finished, I would know how many missed etc...

Comment: You can handle that with a simple `if/else` inside the loop body: `if($CSV1.ContainsKey($row.name)){ $csv1Match = $CSV1[$row.name] }else{ Write-Warning "Skipped $($row.Name) because no matching record was found"; continue }`

Comment: Thanks. I fail to understand how I have been working in C/C++ for so many years and do not know something so simple as Powershell :|

Comment: Just a small BTW... Method invocation failed because [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary] does not contain a method named
'ContainsKey'.

Comment: @NorbertBoros I updated the answer a bit back to use a regular hashtable instead of `[ordered]` (you don't care about the order of the entries in the lookup table anyway), problem should go away if you use the updated version

Comment: My bad, sorry! Checking now :) Thanks!

Comment: FWIW You can still use an ordered dictionary if you want, just change `$CSV1.ContainsKey()` to `$CSV1.Contains()`